# Calculate Compound Interest in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to work out how to calculate the future value of a savings account where each month I must deposit $100.

```py
import pandas as pd

# deposit an extra $100 per month
deposit = [100] * 4
# unbelievable rate of 10%!
rate = [0.1] * 4

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'deposit':deposit, 'rate':rate})
df['interest'] = df.deposit * df.rate
df['total'] = df.deposit.cumsum() + df.interest.cumsum()
```

This gives the incorrect total of $440 when it should be $464.10 due to compound interest.

```py
total = 0
r = 0.1
d = 100
for i in range(0,4):
    total = (total * r) + total + d
    print (total)
```

```
100.0
210.0
331.0
464.1
```

What is the correct way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: why do you need pandas here? why can't you do it using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, it is compounded at the end. Using `pd.Series`'s `shift` and `cumprod`:

```
df['total'] = (df['deposit'] * df['rate'].shift().add(1).cumprod().fillna(1)).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   deposit  rate  interest  total
0      100   0.1      10.0  100.0
1      100   0.1      10.0  210.0
2      100   0.1      10.0  331.0
3      100   0.1      10.0  464.1
```

Comment: How can we amend this solution to cater if the deposit is 0. but the total still increments purely by the interest

Comment: the ammended code is used here
https://hastebin.com/oridapixib.kotlin